# What is the most Pythonic way to map-process lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

This the pseudo-Python-code of what I want to do.

```
albums = map(
  lambda album:
    album + {
      'url': get_url(album['id']),
      'thumb': get_thumb(album['id']),
    },
  albums
)
```

... and here's my currently ugly solution which uses an **or** to return the object after an update.

```
albums = map(
  lambda album:
    album.update({
      'url': get_url(album['id']),
      'thumb': get_thumb(album['id']),
    }) or album,
  albums
)
```

Comment: If you `map` the `album.update()` version, removing the `or` expression, and don't assign it to `albums`, won't you be modifying `albums` to what you want? I'm having trouble fully thinking this through without example data, but it seems like that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `map` is not the right tool to use in Python unless the function you're applying already exists (e.g. a builtin, like `int`, or a method of some existing object). If you're writing a `lambda` to use with `map`, you should instead use either a list comprehension or an explicit `for` loop. In your situation (where you want to do an in-place modification to the dictionaries in your list), I think a `for` loop will be best:

```
for album in albums:
    album["url"] = get_url(album["id"])
    album["thumb"] = get_thumb(album["id"])
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise this would work. I thought Python for loop created copies of objects. This for example doesn't work:

`>>> s = 'hello'
>>> for c in s:
...   c = chr(ord(c)+1)
... 
>>> print(s)
hello`

Why is it that I can edit items within an array of dictionaries but not items within an array of characters?

Comment: strings are immutable objects, and apparent re-assignment is creating a new object.  Re-assignment of indexes in a list would work. `s=['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];for idx, c in enumerate(s): s[idx] += c;`

Answer (score 1):

Since `update` is an inplace operation, i.e. it modifies your existing dicts without needing to assign the result to a variable, you could do:

```
albums = [
    {'id': 111},
    {'id': 222},
    {'id': 333}
]
# Don't assign the result, just modify the existing albums object
map(lambda album:
    album.update(
        {'url': 'http://www.' + str(album['id']) + '.com'}
    ),
    albums
)
```

Result:

```
albums
Out[3]: 
[{'id': 111, 'url': 'http://www.111.com'},
 {'id': 222, 'url': 'http://www.222.com'},
 {'id': 333, 'url': 'http://www.333.com'}]
```

Using `map` to deliberately cause side-effects is a bit awkward though, so the more conventional
for loop option blckknight suggests might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more readable to use `For loop`.

```
for album in albums:
    id = album['id']
    newUrl, newThumb  = get_url(id), get_thumb(id)
    album.update({'url': newUrl, 'thumb': newThumb})
```

But as always I don't know what is the Pythonic...